# How to manipulate PDF in Google Drive API using Python

Tags: python, pdf, google-drive-api

I have to   split a PDF on drive. So i want to know if there are a way to manipulate PDF on Drive API. 
Does anyone know a way to make at least one of these actions

- Split
- get number of page
- cut page
- ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to display the number of pages of a PDF file in Drive, split it into separate PDFs for each page and insert the newly created PDFs back into Drive.

To execute the following code you will need to define a project in the Google Developer Console. You can create a new one at https://console.developers.google.com/project if you do not already have one.

Once your project is created, click on it to open the Project Dashboard. Go to `APIS & Auth` > `Credentials` and create a new OAuth Client ID for an installed application if you do not already have one for this project. Replace client_id, client_secret and redirect_uri in the code below with respectively the Client ID, the Client Secret and the first redirect URI listed.

The program will first open a page in your web browser to obtain a verification code required to create a new OAuth token. It will then ask for the fileId of a PDF file in your drive, will display the number of pages of this PDF and insert each page as a separate PDF back in your drive.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import os
import webbrowser

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaInMemoryUpload
import httplib2
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
import pyPdf


CLIENT_ID = 'client_id'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret'
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
REDIRECT_URI = 'redirect_url'


class GoogleDriveManager(object):

  def __init__(self):
    # Create new Google Drive credentials.
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
        CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    webbrowser.open(authorize_url)
    code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
    self._credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

  def GetFile(self, file_id):
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = self._credentials.authorize(http)
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
    url = drive_service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()['downloadUrl']
    return http.request(url, "GET")[1]

  def GetFileName(self, file_id):
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = self._credentials.authorize(http)
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
    return drive_service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()['title']

  def InsertFile(self, file_name, data, mimeType):
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = self._credentials.authorize(http)
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
    media_body = MediaInMemoryUpload(
        data, mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)
    body = {
      'title': file_name,
      'mimeType': mimeType
    }
    drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Create a drive manager.
  drive_manager = GoogleDriveManager()
  file_id = raw_input('Enter the file id of the pdf file: ').strip()
  file_name, ext = os.path.splitext(drive_manager.GetFileName(file_id))
  # Download the pdf file.
  pdf_data = drive_manager.GetFile(file_id)
  pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(StringIO(pdf_data))
  print "Number of pages: %d" % pdf.getNumPages()
  for i in xrange(pdf.getNumPages()):
    writer = pyPdf.PdfFileWriter()
    writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(i))
    page_data = StringIO()
    writer.write(page_data)
    drive_manager.InsertFile(
        file_name + '-' + str(i) + ext, page_data.getvalue(), 'application/pdf')
```